# IOS, Facebook keeps opening in webview instead of Safari

Tags: ios, facebook, xcode4, integration

I am integrating Facebook to my iOS application and have followed all the steps from [this link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/).
But when I try to login the user, it keeps opening up the sign in page in a `UIWebView` instead of opening in Safari which in turn doesn't work.

Am I missing something here?

> >
>   Turns out my Application was being built on 6.0. It got fixed once I started running it on 4.3.

Comment: Doesn't work how? What error messags(s) do you get? Does it return a blank page? Does it go back to the app eventually? It is really important in order to get help that you be as clear as possible. Otherwise people are just going to pass through your question.

Comment: It would open a facebook webpage in Safari. I would enter my credentials, it would redirect and say that you have already authorized this app. There would be an Okay button to top right, but clicking on it wouldn't do anything. I would eventually have to click X button on top left corner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my Application was being built on 6.0. It got fixed once I started running it on 4.3.